# плавная фиксация навигации

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Имеется навигация, которая находится под шапкой. При скролле страницы на 90px(высота шапки) с помощью js навигации присваивается класс с фиксированным позиционированием. всё работает, всё красиво, но единственное что смущает - это слишком резкое прилипание навигации к нулевой точке. Может быть есть какой либо метод сделать эту процедуру более плавной?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 90) {
        $('.header-bottom').addClass('header-fixed');
    } else {
        $('.header-bottom').removeClass('header-fixed');
    }
});

.header-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    padding: 20px 15px;
}
```

Comment: transition .header-bottom добавить пробовал, не помогает?

Comment: пробовал, не помогает(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n9tc3ct8/

Comment: Спасибо! А можно отрегулировать скорость slideDown?